# Why Spring and Struts MVC implement singleton pattern for their controller classes?

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, singleton, struts

Since the singleton pattern is for stateful objects and the servlet request/response in MVC are normally managed by a stateless object (the controller class) why they use singleton pattern only?

Comment: I'd guess the original S1 devs chose to follow the servlet model. There's also a cost to approaches like Struts 2's instance-per-request, although IMO it's relatively trivial.

Answer (score 2):

Singleton pattern, as described in the GoF book [Design Patterns](http://www.amazon.it/Design-Patterns-Elements-Reusable-Object-Oriented/dp/0201633612), is intended to be applied to **stateless** object. Having only one instance of a Singleton in the application, all its clients share the same instance and then the same state. In most of the cases, this is not the behaviour a object should have. But, it is not a Singleton feature to be *stateless* or *stateful*. It's your design that has to decide if a Singleton should or not have a state.

Speaking about Spring and Struts Controllers, imho it is correct that they are modelled as Singleton. These object should have not a state, and if they have some attributes, they usually are services class, that are Singleton too.

Finally, Controllers' building process has a cost. So it is also for performance reasons that they are implemented as Singleton classes.

Comment: if an object share the same state that object will be not stateless.

Comment: It is not a Singleton feature to be *stateless* or *stateful*. It's your design that has to decide if a Singleton should or not have a state. Usually, it is not a good choice to have a state inside a Singleton, but is perfectly allowed by the pattern.

Comment: Sorry but the existence of a state in a singleton is the primary reason why you should use it.

Comment: Mmmm...wait, the primary reasons to use a Singleton are the following: 1) Only one instance of a class must exist (this could be relaxed); 2) Controlled access to sole instance. I have the GoF book opened here in front of me, and there is no trace of what you're saying :(

Comment: .........Riccardo what is an instance ? isn't just a variable ? thus if you have a unique instance you'll have a single variable instantiated that you decided no other class can modify....;-)

Comment: And so? We are not talking about this, but we are talking about the state and the interface of the Singleton.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79362/discussion-between-fabio-marano-and-riccardo-cardin).